# Overwriting line in txt file by index (Python)

Tags: python

I have this little txt file that originally looks like.

```
29-11-2015 20:17:05 - [Sandy] [20]
29-11-2015 20:17:05 - [Patrick] [5]
29-11-2015 20:17:05 - [MrKrabs] [42]
```

Now I remove the time and add indexes starting from 1. List may be as long as it needs to.

```
with open("database.txt", mode = "r") as text_file:
            print ("\tDatabase: ")
            for iline, line in enumerate(text_file, 1):
                print ("\t\t"+str(iline)+".",line[22:])
```

Now I get this view.

```
Database:
    1. [Sandy] [20]
    2. [Patrick] [5]
    3. [MrKrabs] [42]
```

And after I am asking for help because I need to be able to choose a line depending on index and be able to overwrite it. So it will look like.

```
Choose index you want to change: 1

Write down the name and the number: [MrsPuff] [300]
```

And now the Database becomes

```
Database:
[MrsPuff] [300]
[Patrick] [5]
[MrKrabs] [42]
```

I have been doing this for so long, yet no clue how to do that.

Comment: Add the lines into a list. Then this becomes a trivial exercise.

Comment: He wants to overwrite a single line. Unless he overwrites the entire file, adding them to a list is not going to help him...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I am really new to the coding.

Comment: @hlt yea, i need to overwrite only single line I choose. Everything else has to stay as it is.

Comment: @Moontego text files don't really have lines in them that can be replaced. They are a continuous string of characters with newline characters to demark lines. Once you change one part of the continuous string, the entire rest of the file must be rewritten.

Comment: @tdelaney Okay, then I just need to overwrite it but with the replacement. Can you help me? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: In your existing `for` loop, build those `line[22:]` fragments into a list. When you prompt the user, use that information to modify the proper element of the list. Then open a file for writing and write the list (`'\n'.join(mylist)` will likely do it).